# Using Ansible with Alibaba/Alicloud modules

Tags: module, ansible, cloud

I am relatively new to Ansible, and completely new to Alicloud. I am trying to figure out how I can use the list of modules found here: http://47.88.222.42:8080/ansible-alicloud/latest/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html, or if there is, in fact, a way to do it.
Officially, it seems, Ansible supports only two modules of Alicloud (found here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html), but the other modules I've seen on several websites before as part of tutorials, so I assume they are meant to be working. Can someone help me with this? I was specifically looking at this module: http://47.88.222.42:8080/ansible-alicloud/latest/modules/ali_vpc_module.html#ali-vpc-module

My current issue with it is that when running the playbook with the module, it gives me the error

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'ali_vpc'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the modules by doing `pip install ansible-alicloud`.
Then you will be able to get the `ali_vpc` module from `/home/cheshi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/alicloud/ali_vpc.py`

https://pypi.org/project/ansible-alicloud/